# Unable to connect SVN server

Tags: tortoisesvn

Command: Checkout from svn+ssh://asharma@svntrac.dyyno.corp/apps/svnroot/dyyno, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
Error:  'svn+ssh://asharma@svntrac.dyyno.corp/apps/svnroot/dyyno'
Error: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.
Completed!:

Comment: How about telling something about the background? What is your operating system, what is the version of TortoiseSVN you are using? Have you worked in the past over the protocol `svn+shh`? Are you aware of the documentation at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ssh-howto.html

Comment: Can you ping svntrac.dyyno.corp?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check resolving of svntrac.dyyno.corp from workplace
2. Check connection to svntrac.dyyno.corp with putty
3. Check existence of apps/svnroot/dyyno path (relative to $HOME)
4. [Configure TSVN](http://www.vectorns.com/blog/11-tortoisesvn-over-ssh-on-windows-via-putty) for svn+ssh:// protocol
5. Tell about results